# Как управлять объектом из другого класса?

Tags: android, java

Суть вот такая. Есть библиотека плеера, который я создаю и запускаю при создании активности:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        player = new MODPlayer(getApplicationContext());      
        player.play(this, 1);
        player.onVol(Volum);

    }
```

Запускается это дело в потоке, потом хочу из другой класса активности/класса диалога, скажем прибавить громкость или поставить на паузу, но ведь один экземпляр уже создан! Создать еще один путем player = new MODPlayer(getApplicationContext()) мне кажется будет криво, может можно как то объект передать другому классу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то в андроиде уже есть свой встроенный синглтон и называется он Application, нужно унаследовать от этого класса и хранить там все экземпляры, которые должны быть одиночками, а также добавить геттеры и сеттеры. Особенность этого класса заключается в том, что во-первых есть полная гарантия того, что он будет жить на протяжении всей жизни приложения, в отличии от обычных статических данных, а во-вторых он будет единственны и доступен, если есть контекст приложения. Работать с ним так:

```
player = new MODPlayer();//один раз создаёте свой плеер
getContextApplication().setPlayer(player);//кладём его в аппликейшен
...
context.getPlayer();//а когда нужно просто его от туда достаёте, главное, чтобы был экзепляр контекста
```

Comment: покажи как ты положишь в апликейшн код плеера, что бы getContextApplication().setPlayer(player); этот кусок отработал?

Comment: что значит код? мы туда засовываем экземпляр плеера, он будет единственный и неповторимый)
class MyApplication extends Application{
    private MODPlayer modPlayer;
    
    public void setPlayer(MODPlayer player){
         modPlayer = player;
    }

    public MODPlayer getPlayer(){
         return modPlayer;
    }
}
вот как-то так, я чуток ошибся первый раз, так должно быть:

private MyApplication app;
app = (MyApplication) context.getApplication();
app.getPlayer();

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто ответил, так и сделал! И только сейчас вспомнил, что в java есть pulic static.. Можно бы было обойтись глобальной переменной громкости.

Answer (score 3):

Также как и везде - надо опубликовать методы управления объектом. В вашем случае, видимо, можно сделать так:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private MODPlayer player;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
        player = new MODPlayer(getApplicationContext());       
        player.play(this, 1); 
        player.onVol(Volum); 
    }

    public void setPlayerVolume(int volume) {
     //...
    }
}
```

Теперь, если у вас будет хэндлер на ваш MyActivity, то вы сможете управлять громкостью плеера.

Comment: И получается как вызывать из другого класса? 
    setPlayerVolume(20);
так?

Comment: Ну да, главное чтобы у вас был указатель на активити где лежит плеер. Если нет указателя активити, значит и плеер умер, поскольку (я скромно надеюсь) коли уж он создан в `onCreate()` стало быть и умрет в `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего использовать [синглтон](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: Полностью согласен, в случаях когда нужно чтоб существовал только 1 экземпляр класса используют паттерн синглтон - можешь глянуть,вот - http://www.javenue.info/post/2